# du (disk usage) and format specifier for file/directory sizes strings?

Tags: disk-usage, text-formatting

I am really fond of `du`, and I often like to use it like this:

```
$ du -hsc /var/mail/ /var/log/ 2>/dev/null 
4,0K    /var/mail/
5,7M    /var/log/
5,7M    total
```

However, I'd like to be able to print out sizes in format "[bytes] [kbytes]K [mbytes]M"; and as far as I can see, I cannot do that:

```
$ du -hscb /var/mail/ /var/log/ 2>/dev/null
4096    /var/mail/
14734462    /var/log/
14738558    total

$ du -hsck /var/mail/ /var/log/ 2>/dev/null
4   /var/mail/
5764    /var/log/
5768    total

$ du -hscm /var/mail/ /var/log/ 2>/dev/null
1   /var/mail/
6   /var/log/
6   total

$ # all (b,k,m) here: 
$ du -hscbkm /var/mail/ /var/log/ 2>/dev/null
1   /var/mail/
15  /var/log/
15  total
```

The k,b,m switches simply choose a block size, and then a prefix (K, M) is not even printed (and when you run them all together, you get some weird sizes reported).

Any ideas if there is something like a size format specifier string for `du`?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'du' options are not portable anyway, so just use 'du' and write the suffix after arithmetics in awk for example.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that there isn't anything like a format specifier for `du`, @JiriXichtkniha - cheers!

Comment: For example in AIX du doesn't have -h, so I use -m ;)